# Unable to digital write in NodeMCU ESP8266

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

When I used an example from ESP8266 to do some blinking LED. It works properly but, when I connected to WIFI and MySQL Database, it could not do a digital write LED built-in.

Here is my code in NodeMCU ESP8266:

```
//----------------------------------------Include the NodeMCU ESP8266 Library
//----------------------------------------see here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8jMr94B8iN0 to add NodeMCU ESP8266 library and board
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
//----------------------------------------

//--> Defining an On Board LED (GPIO2 = D4), used for indicators when the process of connecting to a wifi router

#define LED_D8 15 //--> Defines an LED Pin. D8 = GPIO15

//----------------------------------------SSID and Password of your WiFi router.
const char* ssid = "Lenko1"; //--> Your wifi name or SSID.
const char* password = "heryawan1"; //--> Your wifi password.
//----------------------------------------

//----------------------------------------Web Server address / IPv4
// If using IPv4, press Windows key + R then type cmd, then type ipconfig (If using Windows OS).
const char *host = "http://up3manado.com/";
//----------------------------------------

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(500);

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password); //--> Connect to your WiFi router
  Serial.println("");
    
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN,OUTPUT); //--> On Board LED port Direction output
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH); //--> Turn on Led On Board

  pinMode(LED_D8,OUTPUT); //--> LED port Direction output
  digitalWrite(LED_D8, LOW); //--> Turn off Led

  //----------------------------------------Wait for connection
  Serial.print("Connecting");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    //----------------------------------------Make the On Board Flashing LED on the process of connecting to the wifi router.
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
    delay(250);
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
    delay(250);
    //----------------------------------------
  }
  //----------------------------------------
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH); //--> Turn off the On Board LED when it is connected to the wifi router.
  //----------------------------------------If successfully connected to the wifi router, the IP Address that will be visited is displayed in the serial monitor
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Successfully connected to : ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println();
  //----------------------------------------
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  HTTPClient http; //--> Declare object of class HTTPClient

  //----------------------------------------Getting Data from MySQL Database
  String GetAddress, LinkGet, getData;
  int id = 0; //--> ID in Database
  GetAddress = "NodeMCU_Get_Database/GetData.php"; 
  LinkGet = host + GetAddress; //--> Make a Specify request destination
  getData = "ID=" + String(id);
  Serial.println("----------------Connect to Server-----------------");
  Serial.println("Get LED Status from Server or Database");
  Serial.print("Request Link : ");
  Serial.println(LinkGet);
  http.begin(LinkGet); //--> Specify request destination
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");    //Specify content-type header
  int httpCodeGet = http.POST(getData); //--> Send the request
  String payloadGet = http.getString(); //--> Get the response payload from server
  Serial.print("Response Code : "); //--> If Response Code = 200 means Successful connection, if -1 means connection failed. For more information see here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes
  Serial.println(httpCodeGet); //--> Print HTTP return code
  Serial.print("Returned data from Server : ");
  Serial.println(payloadGet); //--> Print request response payload

  if (payloadGet == "1") {
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH); //--> Turn on Led
  }
  if (payloadGet == "0") {
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW); //--> Turn off Led
  }
  //----------------------------------------
  
  Serial.println("----------------Closing Connection----------------");
  http.end(); //--> Close connection
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Please wait 5 seconds for the next connection.");
  Serial.println();
  delay(5000); //--> GET Data at every 5 seconds
}
```

The problem is that I cannot do digitalWrite HIGH if payloadGet == "1". The fact is that I can get the value of payloadGet from MySQL and the value is 1.

Comment: So only the digitalWrite for payLoad fails? The others (within setup etc.) work?
And is this the same script you used to initially test the blinking of the LED? Is the PIN set identically in this script? Last but not least, did you try to execute this without the Serial.begin / Serial.print? Just asking because I experienced similar problems when I used serial and the internal LED (could be fixed by usinf a dedicated LED connected to the board).

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the value of const LED_BUILTIN, it should be 2, not 16. And its behavior is inverted, it turns on at a LOW.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).